# How to solve a Non linear equation?

Tags: python, spyder

I want to know what model to use in order to solve this equation for variable "D" while incrementing "Delta" as shown in the code in order to perform a sensitivity analysis and see how this paramater affects the change in D.
my python version is Python 3.6.0, last updated Dec 23, 2016.

```
#Inputs
k = 80
E_c = 4*10**6
S_c = 700
J = 3.2
C_d = 2
Z_r = -2.327
s_0 = 0.25
W_18 = 10*10**6
Pi = 4.5
Pt = 1.5

#Building the design function

while Pt<3:
    Pt= Pt + 0.0375
    Delta = Pi - Pt

    A = Z_r*s_0 + 7.35*math.log10(D+1) - 0.06
    B = math.log10(((Delta)/(4.5-1.5))/(1+(1.624*10**7)/(D+1)**8.46))
    C = 4.22 - 0.32*Pt
    d = S_c*C_d/(215.63*J)
    E = (D**0.75-1.132)/(D**0.75-(18.42/(E_c/k)**0.25))

    rhs = A+B+C*math.log10(d*E)
    lhs = math.log10(W_18)
    lhs = rhs
```

Comment: Can you provide an image of the equation you're trying to solve or a reference that provides more information about the equation?

Comment: https://www.pavementinteractive.org/reference-desk/design/structural-design/1993-aashto-rigid-pavement-structural-design/

Comment: You should have a look at sympy